# ASP.NET: How to get URL of a file?

Tags: asp.net, favicon, virtual-path

i want to get the fully qualified url to a resource in ASP.NET.

e.g.:

```
<LINK rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=GetFaviconPath()%>">
```

with the code-behind file right now containing:

```
private String GetFaviconPath()
{
   String url = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/clock.ico");
   return url;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because it doesn't return the **fully qualified** path, only the path relative to the server:

```
/Employement/Images/clock.ico
```

Internet Explorer requires a **fully qualified** url, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:62119/Employment/Images/clock.ico

http://avenger:81/Employment/Images/clock.ico

http://MyFreeAspDotNetHosting.com/IanBoyd/Employment/Images/clock.ico
```

How can i get the fully qualified path to a file? i've tried `VirtualPathUtility` and i'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string _ApplicationPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

Append your relative path to that absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

You could append what you have to the result of

Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)

Also, have a look at System.UriBuilder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdwhd34a.aspx